# Linq JS. How to group by repeated?

Tags: javascript, linq, linq.js

I am trying to use linqJS with the following array of objects:

```
var foo = [
    {
        id: 1234,
        index: 0,
    },
    {
        id: 1234,
        index: 1,
    },
    {
        id: 5678,
        index: 2,
    },
    {
        id: 9123,
        index: 3,
    }
];
```

And what I'm trying to do is to group the ones with the repeated **id**, and then, from that group, select the object with the greater index, in this case foo[1]. I haven't use linq much, so I'm not sure if this is possible, this is what I got so far:

```
var bar = Enumerable.From(foo)
    .GroupBy(function (x) { return x.id == x.id; })
    .ToArray();
```

but it ain't working ...
I know how to do this with vanilla JS, but I was hoping to use the plugin.

Any help is appreciated!.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aguerrero_g87/dUy7b/

Comment: `.GroupBy(function (x) { return x.id; })`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Enumerable.From(foo)
          .GroupBy(function(x) { return x.id })
          .Select(function(x)
                  {
                  return x.Max(function(z) { return z.index });
                  })
          .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var bar = Enumerable.From(foo)
    .GroupBy("$.id")
    .Select("$.OrderByDescending('$.index').First()")
    .ToArray();
```